# Does axum's shared state have to be wrapped in an Arc<Mutex> when using an inmemory repository pattern?

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I have a chicken-before-the-egg kind of question, I think...

I have implemented an inmemory repository using an IndexMap, as below:

```
type Db = Arc<RwLock<IndexMap<Uuid, Project>>>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ProjectRepository {
  db: Db,
}
```

I want to share the ProjectRepository as axum's state for a simple rest API.
The shared state is defined in the following code -- Please note that I do not use Arc:

```
use ps_infrastructure_db::repository::ProjectRepository;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct AppState {
    pub project_repository: ProjectRepository,
}

impl AppState {
    async fn app_state_factory() -> AppState {
        AppState {
            project_repository: ProjectRepository::new(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct SharedState {
    pub app_state: AppState,
}

impl SharedState {
    pub async fn shared_state_factory() -> SharedState {
        SharedState{ app_state: AppState::app_state_factory().await}
    }
}
```

Finally, I provide the shared state to the axum server:

```
let state = SharedState::shared_state_factory().await?;
let controller = Controller::new()?;
let app = configure_middleware(controller).await?
    .with_state(state);
```

QUESTION:

Since the inmemory database inside the ProjectRepository is wrapped by `Arc<RwLock>`, is it necessary to wrap the app_state field in the SharedState struct with an Arc or `Arc<Muxex>`, too?
For example:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct SharedState {
    pub app_state: Arc<AppState>,
}
```

It seems to me that this would lead to deadlock.

Should I remove the `Arc<RwLock>` wrapper from ProjectRepository's database definition and only use `Arc<Mutex>` for the app_state field in SharedState?  I like the `Arc<RwLock>` that exists in ProjectRepository in case I want to reuse the crate in another application.

Thank you for your time and interest,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

Since you derive `Clone` on all of the layers up to the `Arc`, you do not need to wrap it in anything. When you extract a `T` with axum's `State<T>` wrapper, it extracts a `T` by cloning the existing `T`. In your case, this winds up cloning the backing `Arc` and providing a *new* `SharedState` wrapper around it.

If you add other fields to the `SharedState` struct, that may change things. As long as all fields are of a type implementing `Clone` then it will *work* but may be inefficient if those values are expensive to clone. In that case you could consider wrapping each field in `Arc` or you could choose to use `Arc<SharedState>` as your state type -- you'd have an `Arc` in an `Arc`, but this is usually innocuous and may even be useful in some cases.

It's hard to say exactly what you should do without knowing the other fields you plan to add to `SharedState`.